# How to delete formula from xlsx file using poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a xlsx file which contains formula for some of cells. I knew the index of the row as well the cell which contains formula. I just need to delete the formula nor the value which is in the particular cell. Is it possible? Like below:

```
I have the below formula for 1st row 3rd cell

Formula is SUM(A1:D1) and value of cell is 4;
```

I just want to keep "4" the cell value as its, only remove the formula "(SUM(A1:D1))" using POI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [FormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(Cell)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateInCell%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29). As explained in the javadocs:

> If cell contains formula, it evaluates the formula, and puts the formula result back into the cell, in place of the old formula. Else if cell does not contain formula, this method leaves the cell unchanged.

You can find more details and example in the [Apache POI documentation on evaluating formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#EvaluateInCell), but basically you just need to follow the example code given there, eg

```
File file = new File("/somepath/test.xls");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// suppose your formula is in B3
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3");
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
```

Comment: still after that if you try **cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);** you will get: **Cannot get a numeric value from a text formula cell**

Comment: So, your solution is of limited use - for numeric formulas only? Anyway, I had numerical formulas and used your solution. (+ added cell.setValue(""); at the end)

Comment: Sorry, replied to wrong post. `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell` should work for all formulas of all types. Explicitly setting the cell type wipes the formula but keeps the last-evaluated value, but you need to check the last-evaluated type first.